# i am unable to reset my skype password?

Tags: skype

i am unable to reset my skype password can any one help mee?

Comment: Ok, try to put some information on your question. What have you already tried ? When are you stuck in the reset procedure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try https://login.skype.com/account/password-reset-request

If that doesn't help you, there is not much that we can do for you...